# PHP spawns 20-30 sessions per second then stops

Tags: php, session

I run PHP 5.6 on Windows Server 2012. The server serves a single page that begins with session_start(); because the page needs sessions to handle the data. It's a submission form in multiple steps.

Currently the session directory is being filled at speeds of around 20-30 new session files per second. I don't understand how. Garbage collection doesn't seem to be doing anything as the files fill up faster than they grow old, so to speak.

No entries in the error log. No loops running that could cause this.

Page activity according to Google Analytics does not indicate anything near this amount of "new hits". Site works perfectly though.

Then, out of the blue, the files stop spawning. Nothing happens. Everything still works as it's supposed to. This has happened before and suddenly they start spawning again at insane rates.

Anyone care to venture as guess how this can happen?

Comment: Did you check your server's access logs? THose will show all page hits. Google Analytics might miss some, depending on how you implemented their tracking. If you see that many hits in your server's access logs, you might be target of some minor DoS attack.

Comment: I think I know why.
The link has been shared on facebook, so every time it's shown to a user in their newsfeed (even if they don't click it) I think it somehow initiates a connection to the site that is then never used. Seems like I basically DDoS'ed myself.

Comment: I upvoted for your honesty with the DDoS. And I laughed - I can imagine myself doing something similar. Thank you

Comment: Garbage collector has started throwing out session files now. So it seems to be working. I guess I need to redesign it so the shared link is not the one initiating a session... such as having a "Click to begin" button that redirects somewhere else.